# left join vs another query to get comments of post?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, left-join

I'm trying two get post and the two recent comments. I want the results to not be duplicated which happens with left join. I want the result in json format like this

```
{
postid 
title 
body 
comments: []
}
```

is it better to do a left join and then somehow collapse the rows or is it better to get the post and then do another query to get the comments. Any simple code examples will be very helpful

EDIT

i have two tables

```
POST{
    postID, 
    uid,
    title,
    body,
    Date
}

Comments{
    commentID,
    postID
    uid,
    text,
    Date
}
```

this is the query im using for posts

```
SELECT * from posts WHERE posts.id = ?
```

Comment: Can you show your data and wanted output?

Comment: sorry about that, i added more details. The expected output is on the top. I want it in json format with comments as an array. I am also looking for an approach that is scalable and efficient, thanks

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please ask 1 specific non-duplicate question per post. Please don't ask new questions in comments, post a new question. Show what parts you are able to do & explain re the 1st place you are stuck. PS "scalable" & "efficient" don't mean anything until you define them. Learn to make straightforward designs.

Comment: Thanks for these guidelines. Im pretty new here so i ll try to follow these. Just from reading my question could you give any advice on this

Answer (score 1):

You can put this into a Postgres array as:

```
select p.postid, p.title, p.body,
       array_agg(c.text) as comments
from posts p left join
     comments c
     using (postid)
group by p.postid;
```

And as a json/jsonb array with very similar syntax:

```
select p.postid, p.title, p.body,
       jsonb_agg(c.text) as comments
from posts p left join
     comments c
     using (postid)
group by p.postid;
```